# Response.AddHeader seeing file path as file name

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have an ImageButton control within a ListView which, when clicked, should download the image with the right ID.

Here's the ImageButton ASPX:

```
<asp:ImageButton runat="server" ID="ibtDownloadImage" ImageUrl="img/downloadIcon.png" OnClick="ibtDownloadImage_OnClick" CommandArgument='<%# Convert.ToString(Eval("ID"))+Convert.ToString(Eval("FileExtension")) %>' />
```

As you can see, when it is clicked, it executes the "ibtDownloadImage_OnClick" method and sets the command argument to the ID plus the FileExtension (for example, 1.jpg, which is the name of the image).

My C# code for the ibtDownloadImageOnClick is:

```
protected void ibtDownloadImage_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {


            ImageButton img = (ImageButton)sender;
            string file = img.CommandArgument;

            String imgURLtoDownload = @"img/uploads/"+file;


            Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + imgURLtoDownload);
        }
```

When I click the ImageButton control, it downloads a file called "img-uploads-1.jpg" (without the speech marks), so it seems to be taking what I intended to be the filepath as part of the name, and replacing the / with -...

Any ideas on how to fix this? It seems like it should be a simple solution.

I've run debugging with a breakpoint on the Response.AddHeader line and imgURLtoDownload's content is img/upload/1.jpg (as it should be)..

Comment: `Response.ContentType =` where is this part of the code being assigned.. also is this line correct ` String imgURLtoDownload = @"img/uploads/"+file;` should it be pointing to ` ImageUrl="img/downloadIcon.png"`  also try adding a `~` before img if you are having problems as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can read file content as binary, let say you have function for this , that takes file name get byte array as binary content, and that function name `GetFileContent(Filepath)`. Then you can use that function to write content to response and yet specify custom path.

```
ImageButton img = (ImageButton)sender;
string file = img.CommandArgument;
String imgURLtoDownload = @"img/uploads/"+file;
byte[] data= GetFileContent(Server.MapPath(imgURLtoDownload));
Response.Clear();
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + file);
Response.ContentType = System.Web.MimeMapping.GetMimeMapping(Server.MapPath(imgURLtoDownload));     
Response.BinaryWrite(data);
Response.End();


public byte[] GetFileContent(string Filepath)
{
    return System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(Filepath);
}
```

Comment: With that code, I get the error: "Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS Express\img\uploads\1.jpg'." when I click the button. It can't seem to go to the parent directory

Comment: Nevermind, didn't see you added Server.MapPath! That's completely fixed it, thanks so much!

Comment: one more thing: the downloaded files can be either .jpg, .png .jpeg, or .gif. How should I expand the Response.ContentType?

Comment: For unknown filetype, `application/octet-stream` is used, and you can try with this, else check extension, based on that set content type. In meantime, let me look at other options.

Comment: @Frayt, however i have updated code, found way to get `mimetype`, may be you can use that in other required place.